# Minecraft Spigot, PlayerInteractEvent cannot be passed

Tags: java, minecraft

I've got a problem with my Spigot Plugin for the 1.17.1. I tried to implement an event when a totem of undying is clicked that it would open an inventory. After couple of hours and reading some posts, nothing helped me and I'm stuck. Can anybody help me?

Here's my code:

```
public class HerrDesWindesTalisman implements Listener{

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract (PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    Action a = e.getAction();
    if(a.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)  || a.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
        p.sendMessage("Warpmenü");
        if(e.getItem() != null && e.getItem().getType().equals(Material.TOTEM_OF_UNDYING)) {
            Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(p, 27*9, "Ziele");
            ItemStack item1 = new ItemStack(Material.ACACIA_DOOR);
            ItemMeta imeta1 = item1.getItemMeta();
            imeta1.setDisplayName("Reise nach Irgendwo");
            item1.setItemMeta(imeta1);
            inv.setItem(5, item1);
            p.openInventory(inv);
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should check that this listener is will registered. So in your main class, don't forget to add :

```java
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new HerrDesWindesTalisman(), this);
}
```

Also, the size of inventory should be between 9 and 54, and a multiple of 9.

Actually, you are using "27 * 9". I think you was thinking about a size of 27 (so 9 * 3). Do it, use this line:

```
Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(p, 27, "Ziele");
```

Comment: Heya,
I really forgot to register this event, thank you. But now I got another problem;
My console tells me the error: 'Fatal error trying to convert StartUp v1.0:de/Daniel260/startup/items/HerrDesWindesTalisman.class
org.bukkit.plugin.AuthorNagException: No legacy enum constant for TOTEM_OF_UNDYING. Did you forget to define a modern (1.13+) api-version in your plugin.yml?'

What can I do about that? If you need anything of my project, just text me. 

Thank you

Comment: No, I don't need anything else. It's another issue, which is fully explain in the error. You can find doc [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/). You should add `api-version: 1.13` in your `plugin.yml` file